# dust.js format text through a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, socket.io, dust.js

I've got a javascript function which blur's text:

```
function blurlines(data) {
    var dataSplit = data.split(" ");
    var lastWord = dataSplit.pop();
    var toBlur = '<span class="blur">' + dataSplit.join(" ") +  '</span>'; 
// Blur entire sentace, show only last word
     var output = '<li>' + toBlur + lastWord + '</li>';
     return output;
}
```

I'm trying to get this to work with dust.js by trying something like:

```
{#storylines}
    <script>
        blurlines("{text}");
    </script>                   
{/storylines}
```

Is there anyway to easily pass the {text} value through a JS function and then render the output?

If i run it in console it seems to work:

`> blurlines("This is a test line")`

`> "<li><span class="blur">This is a test</span>line</li>"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do something similar, create a helper function in my global context:

```
var dustCtx = dust.makeBase({
    blurText: function(chunk, context, bodies, params) { 
        var dataSplit = params.data.split(" ");
        var lastWord = dataSplit.pop();
        var toBlur = '<span class="blur">' + dataSplit.join(" ") +  '</span>'; 
        var output = '<li>' + toBlur + lastWord + '</li>';
        return chunk.write(output);
    }
});
```

Merge it with local context on render:

```
dust.render("template", dustCtx.push({storylines:...}), function(err, out) {});
```

And then call it like this:

```
{#storylines}
    {#blurText data=text/}
{/storylines}
```

This approach might be handy for passing additional parameters if you wanted to control the blurring for example.

Comment: Where would i create the helper function, i'm not familiar with it

Comment: Helper functions need to be properties in your context object, probably the same place you created your filter from what I understand about filters.  In the above example, the dustCtx variable just needs to be accessible when you call dust.render, you can see the dustCtx.push() will merge your own context with dustCtx such that you can fill dustCtx with useful functions and re-use.

Comment: Apologies, it looks like filters are added by extending dust.filters so they do work differently (sorry not used them extensively yet).  You should however still be calling dust.render() and the second argument to this is your context, as a simple demo you can just add the blurText function as above to your context and it should work as above.

Answer (score 2):

I created a dust.js filter to get it to work

```
  bl: function(value){  var dataSplit = value.split(" ");
    var lastWord = dataSplit.pop();
    var toBlur = '<span class="blur">' + dataSplit.join(" ") +  '</span>'; 
     var output = toBlur + lastWord;
     return output; }
```

and am passing the below in the template:

```
{#storylines}
    <li>{text|bl|s}</li>    
{/storylines}
```